# Injection DLL it doesn't work

Tags: c++

i have a DLL

```
#include <windows.h>
     BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved )
    {
            switch (fdwReason)
        {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                MessageBox(NULL, "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", "", MB_OK);
                hWndProc();
                break;

            case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                MessageBox(NULL, "DLL_PROCESS_DETACH", "", MB_OK);
                break;

            case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                MessageBox(NULL, "DLL_THREAD_ATTACH", "", MB_OK);
                break;

            case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
                MessageBox(NULL, "DLL_THREAD_DETACH", "", MB_OK);
                break;
        }
        return TRUE; // succesful
    }
```

I use Winject to inject this DLL in a process, but when the DLL is in that process then it don't work. Message box aren't displayed.

Comment: Are you trying to inject your dll into the system service process?

Comment: Many things can go wrong here.  Google "windows loader lock" to get started.